# Querying status of symbolic links

Tags: bash, find, symlink

Say I want to query what symlinks pointing to where (directory, regular file, non-existent file, etc):

```bash
ls -aRl | grep '^l' | awk '{print $9 "\t" $11}'
```

which is inefficient compared to:

```bash
find -type l -printf "%f\t%l\n"
```

But first command gives me colors depending on the link type. The second doesn't.

Is there a program for colorizing paths or a better way to query the status of symbolic links?

I've taken a look on `man dircolors` but it seems to only provide definitions for `ls`.

Comment: `find ... | xargs ls {}` ? Good luck.

Comment: See: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: The first command gives you colours only if you had set the environment variable to `LS_COLOURS` to `always` (which would be a bad idea anyway). Otherwise, since the `ls` output goes to a pipe, _ls_ would not create ANSI colour code to the output.

Answer (score 1):

If `ls` is doing what you want, just use `ls` for displaying it:

```bash
find -type l -exec ls -l --color=auto '{}' \;
```

If you are not interested in the path of the symbolic link, use

```
find -type l -execdir ls -l --color=auto '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [GNU Findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html), the `%Y` format for the `-printf` option of `find` may be of use.  It prints a single character that gives the type of the file referenced by a symlink (`f` for regular file, `d` for directory, `N` for non-existent, ...).

```
find . -type l -printf '%Y %p\n'
```

will print the types and paths of all symlinks under the current directory.  Note that the output will be difficult to parse if any of the paths contain newline characters.  To produce output that can be parsed unambiguously for all possible paths, use the [NUL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) character to terminate the output for each link:

```
find . -type l -printf '%Y %p\0'
```

Be aware that this will not tell you if the target of a symlink is another symlink.  All symlinks are dereferenced before determining the type (if any) of the target.